# Combine histogram with describe in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Is there a way to combine the display the output from df.describe() and df[name].plot.hist() or any other histogram plotting command. A while ago I found a way to combine both in one graph or at least next to each other but I cannot find how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate a plt table with the pandas histogram like so

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
axes = df['A'].hist()

plt.legend(df.columns)
dfsummary = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].describe())

plt.table(cellText=dfsummary.values,
      colWidths = [0.4]*2,
      rowLabels=dfsummary.index,
      colLabels=dfsummary.columns,
      cellLoc = 'right', rowLoc = 'right',
      loc='top')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much James, this looks very good. I am very sorry to be this picky, but I remember vaguely that my previous approach was simpler though, there was some option in matplotly to add the describe table in there.

Comment: The plot appeared on the left and on the right I had a table. I saved the actual graphs but I cannot find the code that created it. I am going to leave this open, in case someone might know. Thank you so much for your help though!!